# How to add a date filter in full calendar

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

How can I add a date filter in full calendar, example: go to 2017-12-15?

I want the user to select a specific date to show related events.

Is it possible to do that?

Comment: You mean, how to programmatically go to a date? Docs: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/current_date/gotoDate/

Comment: Would you have an example? I read the documentation but I did not understand how to implement it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, initialize fullcalendar with any of the supported options. Next, call the `gotoDate` method using the trigger of your choice. In this example, the trigger will be a button click.

**HTML**

```
<div id="my_calendar"></div>

<button id="my_button">Go to 2017-12-15</button>
```

**JS**

```
$(function(){

  $('#my_calendar').fullCalendar({
    // your options here...
  });

  $('#my_button').click(function(){

    // call fullCalendar 'gotoDate' method
    $('#my_calendar').fullCalendar('gotoDate', '2017-12-15');

  });

});
```

Comment: Fantastic ! Tks